# Using Regular Expressions to find a line starting with specific number of spaces only

Tags: regex

i just want to ask how to create a regular expression that will read the line that starts with space, but the amount of starting spaces should not equal to 7.

Example (assume that the dashes are the starting point for every line):

```
-       *THIS LINE HAS STARTING SEVEN SPACES.. SO THIS LINE WILL NOT BE DETECTED.
-   *THIS LINE HAS STARTING THREE SPACES.. THIS LINE WILL BE DETECTED.
-          *THIS LINE HAS STARTING TEN SPACES.. THIS LINE WILL BE DETECTED.
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Perl regular expression matches what you want:

```
^(\s{0,6}|\s{8,})(?=\S)/
```

- `^` - Anchor at the start
- `\s` - matches a single whitespace
- `\s{0,6}|\s{8,}` - matches *0 to 6* **or** *8 and more* whitespaces
- `(?=)` - [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- `(?=\S)` - Lookahead to see if there is exists a non-whitespace character

Comment: on spaces 6 and below.. it works.. but unfortunately, on 8 and above, it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I have updated my answer. It should match now.